# Converting SQL Statement with Multiple Left Outer Joins and Various Clauses to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I've been trying to create associations and navigation properties to simplify my LINQ query a little; however, because of the complicated, proprietary database I'm working with it's been really difficult.

For most of this process, I've been using the database first approach on EF5. I couldn't create associations and navigation properties using database first, so I tried to create foreign keys on SQL Server, but was unsuccessful in that.

For my next step, I tried to create the tables, associations, and navigation properties using the code first approach; however, again, because of the necessities of the database and server I'm working with, I was unsuccessful in simplifying my query.

My last resort is just to do what I was originally trying to do in this question. That is to get this LINQ query:

```
from item in db2.OrderFormDump
join icp in db2.IcPricP on item.NODASHITEMNO equals icp.ITEMNO into icpGroup
from iG in icpGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join itemInfo in db2.WebItemInfo on item.ITEMNO equals itemInfo.ITEMNO into itemInfoGroup
from iIG in itemInfoGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join weboeordh in db2.WebOEOrdH on "brian" equals weboeordh.USER into weboeordhGroup
from wOEODHG in weboeordhGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join weboeordd in db2.WebOEOrdD on new { itemno = item.NODASHITEMNO, orduniq = wOEODHG.ORDUNIQ } equals new { itemno = weboeordd.ITEMNO, orduniq = weboeordd.ORDUNIQ } into weboeorddGroup
from wOEODG in weboeorddGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join weboeordsubmit in db2.WebOEOrdSubmit on wOEODG.ORDUNIQ equals weboeordsubmit.ORDUNIQ into weboeordsubmitGroup
from wOEOSG in weboeordsubmitGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join webloginaccess in db2.WebLoginAccess on "brian" equals webloginaccess.USER into webloginaccessGroup
from wLAG in webloginaccessGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
join arcus in db2.Arcus on wLAG.CUSTID equals arcus.IDCUST into arcusGroup
from aG in arcusGroup
where (item.ALLOWINBC == "Yes" && item.ALLOWINAB == "Yes")
&& (item.BASEDESCRIPTION.Contains("dude") || item.DESCRIPTION.Contains("dude") || item.CATEGORY.Contains("dude") || item.FOODACCSPEC.Contains("dude") || item.ITEMBRAND.Contains("dude") || item.ITEMGROUP.Contains("dude") || item.ITEMNO.Contains("dude") || item.ITEMSUBTYPE.Contains("dude") || item.ITEMTYPE.Contains("dude") || iIG.INFO.Contains("dude") || item.UPC.Contains("dude") || item.UPC.Substring(2, 10).Contains("dude"))
&& (iG.CURRENCY == "CDN" && iG.DPRICETYPE == 1)
&& wOEODG.ORDUNIQ != wOEODHG.ORDUNIQ
&& iG.PRICELIST == aG.PRICLIST
orderby item.BASEDESCRIPTION
select new { item.ITEMNO, item.BASEDESCRIPTION, iIG.INFO, item.UPC, iG.UNITPRICE, item.CASEQTY, wOEODG.QTY } into x
group x by new { x.ITEMNO, x.BASEDESCRIPTION, x.INFO, x.UPC, x.UNITPRICE, x.CASEQTY, x.QTY } into items
select items;
```

To get the same results as this SQL query:

```
DECLARE @search varchar(50) = 'dude'

SELECT orderformdump.itemno,basedescription,info,upc,CAST(UNITPRICE AS DECIMAL(18,2)),caseqty, sum(qty) AS userquantity
FROM PPPLTD.[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP] 
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.ICPRICP ON replace(PPPLTD.[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP].[ITEMNO],'-','') = ICPRICP.ITEMNO
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.WEBITEMINFO ON ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO = WEBITEMINFO.ITEMNO
LEFT JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordh ON [user] = 'brian'
LEFT JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordd ON pppltd.dbo.WEBOEORDD.ITEMNO = REPLACE(pppltd.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO,'-','') and weboeordd.ORDUNIQ = weboeordh.orduniq
Left JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordsubmit ON weboeordsubmit.orduniq = weboeordd.ORDUNIQ and weboeordd.ORDUNIQ != weboeordsubmit.orduniq
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.WEBLOGINACCESS ON WEBLOGINACCESS.[USER] = 'brian'
LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.ARCUS ON ARCUS.IDCUST = WEBLOGINACCESS.CUSTID
where (allowinbc = 'Yes' or allowinab = 'Yes') 
AND [PRICELIST] = ARCUS.PRICLIST 
and [CURRENCY] = 'CDN' and DPRICETYPE = 1
and (itemgroup like '%' + @search + '%' or itemtype like '%' + @search + '%' or itembrand like '%' + @search + '%' 
or subcat  like '%' + @search + '%' or orderformdump.description  like '%' + @search + '%' or basedescription like '%'+ @search + '%' 
or orderformdump.ITEMNO like '%'+@search+'%' or UPC like '%'+@search+'%' or (select top 1 1 from pppltd.dbo.ICITEMO where OPTFIELD like 'UPC%' and VALUE like '%'+@search+'%' 
and ITEMNO = pppltd.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.itemno) is not null) 
group by ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO,BASEDESCRIPTION,info,UPC,CAST(UNITPRICE AS DECIMAL(18,2)),caseqty
order by basedescription
```

When I execute the LINQ on LINQPad, it produces this SQL:

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '-'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p2 VarChar(1000) = 'brian'
DECLARE @p3 NVarChar(1000) = '-'
DECLARE @p4 NVarChar(1000) = ''
DECLARE @p5 VarChar(1000) = 'brian'
DECLARE @p6 VarChar(1000) = 'Yes'
DECLARE @p7 VarChar(1000) = 'Yes'
DECLARE @p8 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p9 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p10 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p11 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p12 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p13 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p14 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p15 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p16 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p17 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p18 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p19 Int = 2
DECLARE @p20 Int = 10
DECLARE @p21 VarChar(1000) = '%dude%'
DECLARE @p22 VarChar(1000) = 'CDN'
DECLARE @p23 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t10].[ITEMNO], [t10].[BASEDESCRIPTION], [t10].[value] AS [INFO], [t10].[UPC], [t10].[value2] AS [UNITPRICE], [t10].[CASEQTY], [t10].[value3] AS [QTY]
FROM (
    SELECT [t9].[ITEMNO], [t9].[BASEDESCRIPTION], [t9].[value], [t9].[UPC], [t9].[value2], [t9].[CASEQTY], [t9].[value3]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[ITEMNO], [t0].[BASEDESCRIPTION], [t2].[INFO] AS [value], [t0].[UPC], [t1].[UNITPRICE] AS [value2], [t0].[CASEQTY], [t5].[QTY] AS [value3], [t0].[ALLOWINBC], [t0].[ALLOWINAB], [t0].[DESCRIPTION], [t0].[CATEGORY], [t0].[FOODACCSPEC], [t0].[ITEMBRAND], [t0].[ITEMGROUP], [t0].[ITEMSUBTYPE], [t0].[ITEMTYPE], [t1].[CURRENCY], [t1].[DPRICETYPE], [t5].[ORDUNIQ], [t4].[ORDUNIQ] AS [ORDUNIQ2], [t1].[PRICELIST], [t8].[PRICLIST]
        FROM [ORDERFORMDUMP] AS [t0]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [ICPRICP] AS [t1] ON REPLACE([t0].[ITEMNO], @p0, @p1) = [t1].[ITEMNO]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [WEBITEMINFO] AS [t2] ON [t0].[ITEMNO] = [t2].[ITEMNO]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT [t3].[ORDUNIQ]
            FROM [WEBOEORDH] AS [t3]
            WHERE @p2 = [t3].[USER]
            ) AS [t4] ON 1=1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [WEBOEORDD] AS [t5] ON (REPLACE([t0].[ITEMNO], @p3, @p4) = [t5].[ITEMNO]) AND ([t4].[ORDUNIQ] = [t5].[ORDUNIQ])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT [t6].[CUSTID]
            FROM [WEBLOGINACCESS] AS [t6]
            WHERE @p5 = [t6].[USER]
            ) AS [t7] ON 1=1 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [ARCUS] AS [t8] ON [t7].[CUSTID] = [t8].[IDCUST]
        ) AS [t9]
    WHERE ([t9].[ALLOWINBC] = @p6) AND ([t9].[ALLOWINAB] = @p7) AND (([t9].[BASEDESCRIPTION] LIKE @p8) OR ([t9].[DESCRIPTION] LIKE @p9) OR ([t9].[CATEGORY] LIKE @p10) OR ([t9].[FOODACCSPEC] LIKE @p11) OR ([t9].[ITEMBRAND] LIKE @p12) OR ([t9].[ITEMGROUP] LIKE @p13) OR ([t9].[ITEMNO] LIKE @p14) OR ([t9].[ITEMSUBTYPE] LIKE @p15) OR ([t9].[ITEMTYPE] LIKE @p16) OR ([t9].[value] LIKE @p17) OR ([t9].[UPC] LIKE @p18) OR (SUBSTRING([t9].[UPC], @p19 + 1, @p20) LIKE @p21)) AND ([t9].[CURRENCY] = @p22) AND ([t9].[DPRICETYPE] = @p23) AND ([t9].[ORDUNIQ] <> [t9].[ORDUNIQ2]) AND ([t9].[PRICELIST] = [t9].[PRICLIST])
    GROUP BY [t9].[ITEMNO], [t9].[BASEDESCRIPTION], [t9].[value], [t9].[UPC], [t9].[value2], [t9].[CASEQTY], [t9].[value3]
    ) AS [t10]
ORDER BY [t10].[BASEDESCRIPTION]
```

**UPDATE**

As per HBomb's answer, I decided to create a stored procedure with parameters instead of doing multiple joins:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PRODUCT_PROCEDURE

    @USERID VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT distinct datawarehouse.dbo.orderformdump.itemno, basedescription,info,upc,CAST((SELECT [UNITPRICE] FROM PPPLTD.dbo.[ICPRICP] WHERE [ITEMNO] = replace([DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP].[ITEMNO],'-','') AND [PRICELIST] = (select top 1 priclist from PPPLTD.dbo.ARCUS where IDCUST = (select top 1 CUSTID from PPPLTD.dbo.WEBLOGINACCESS where [USER] = @USERID)) and [CURRENCY] = 'CDN' and DPRICETYPE = 1) AS DECIMAL(18,2))as price,caseqty, qty AS userquantity FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[ORDERFORMDUMP] LEFT JOIN pppltd.dbo.weboeordd ON pppltd.dbo.WEBOEORDD.ITEMNO = REPLACE(datawarehouse.dbo.ORDERFORMDUMP.ITEMNO,'-','') and orduniq not in (select orduniq from pppltd.dbo.weboeordsubmit) and WEBOEORDD.ORDUNIQ in (select orduniq from pppltd.dbo.weboeordh where [user] = @USERID) LEFT JOIN DATAWAREHOUSE.dbo.webiteminfo on webiteminfo.itemno = orderformdump.itemno where (allowinbc = 'Yes' or allowinab = 'Yes') order by BASEDESCRIPTION

END
```

Then I used Entity Framework's Database First approach to add my stored procedure and it has created a new DbContext with a method that sets the 'USERID' parameter in my stored procedure:

```
public partial class DataWarehouseEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DataWarehouseEntities()
            : base("name=DataWarehouseEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual ObjectResult<PRODUCT_PROCEDURE_Result> PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(string USERID)
        {
            var USERIDParameter = USERID != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("USERID", USERID) :
                new ObjectParameter("USERID", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<PRODUCT_PROCEDURE_Result>("PRODUCT_PROCEDURE", USERIDParameter);
        }
    }
```

I've also tried:

```
var USERIDParameter = USERID != null ? new SqlParameter("USERID", USERID) : new SqlParameter("USERID", typeof(string));

return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<PRODUCT_PROCEDURE‌​_Result>("PRODUCT_PROCEDURE @USERID", USERIDParameter);
```

and finally, I tried running a much more simplified LINQ query on the results of my stored procedure:

```
var products = db2.PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(username).Where
                        (item => item.basedescription.Contains(searchword) 
                         || item.info.Contains(searchword)
                         || item.itemno.Contains(searchword)
                         || item.itemno.Contains(searchword.Replace("-", ""))
                         || item.upc.Contains(searchword));
```

However, now I'm getting a ***NullReferenceException*** because the query isn't returning any results.

**UPDATE #2**

Executing the stored procedure is not causing the NullReferenceException. the problem is the LINQ query.

I found out that when I have `var products = db2.PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(username).ToList()` alone, it returns results, but as soon as I try to add a `where` clause on it, it returns null.

**SOLUTION**

With HBomb's help, I solved this issue. First of all, instead creating multiple joins in LINQ, or create associations, and navigation properties, it's much easier to create a view or a stored procedure in your database then write a simple LINQ query using the results of that (example of how to do that is above).

I found out that I was getting my ***NullReferenceException*** because some values in the database for my `info` property were null. All I had to do to fix that issue was modify the stored procedure to change to `info` column to `isnull(info,'') as info`.

Lastly, just for better search results, I changed my query:

```
var searchWords = searchword.ToLower().Split(' ');

            var products = db2.PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(username).ToList()
            .Where
                    (item => item.basedescription.ToLower().Contains(searchWords[0])
                     || item.info.ToLower().Contains(searchWords[0])
                     || item.itemno.Contains(searchword)
                     || item.itemno.Contains(searchword.Replace("-", ""))
                     || item.upc.Contains(searchword)
                     || (item.price.ToString() == searchword
                     && item.price.ToString() != null));

            if (searchWords.Length > 1)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < searchWords.Length-1; x++)
                {
                    products = products.Where(i => i.basedescription.ToLower().Contains(searchWords[x]) || i.info.ToLower().Contains(searchWords[x]));
                }
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: without aliases on your Select columns, there's really no way to help

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Or what ORM are you using? With EF, you don't need to do manual joins, you can use navigation properties.

Comment: FYI - using REPLACE on an indexed column (item.ITEMNO.Replace("-", "")) will cost you a ton of CPU.  Better to add a computed field with the hyphens and index and match on that.

Comment: @Sahuagin I'm using EF. How would I use navigation properties in a LINQ query? I used Database First to generate my model properties.

Comment: @JohnPasquet thanks for that tip! I'll create computed properties for that.

Comment: The maintainability of your sample is questionable. Why do you want to convert this?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I'm updating old code that uses raw SQL to get results. Also, LINQ has better search capabilities.

Comment: @Sahuagin I'm trying to use navigation properties as per your recommendation, but now I'm getting an error. I've updated my post with what I've done so far.

Comment: @bkhosh2 with EF, the LINQ is converted directly into SQL. this means that you can't use things that are not a part of the model, or that EF doesn't know how to convert to SQL. In your case, the `ICPRICP` property *looks* like a navigation property, but it must not be properly mapped in the EF model or something. Also, you still have join-like where clauses (`item.WEBITEMINFO.ITEMNO == item.ITEMNO`) which are unnecessary if you have working navigation properties. Your need for using `NODASHITEMNO` in some joins might make those particular associations difficult to make as well.

Comment: do you have an .edmx file? on the graphical model you should have lines between your entities (associations). if you don't you can right-click to add an association. the association can have navigation properties at each end, and can have a referential constraint. I'm not entirely sure how to approach it though, since you're doing database-first. I almost always do model-first myself.

Comment: @Sahuagin yes, database first creates a .edmx file for you. I will try associating the properties using the GUI. Thanks!

Comment: @Sahuagin when you create associations in the .edmx file, how does EF know to associate the navigation properties with the correct column/model property? For example, If I make an association between ORDERFORMDUMP and ICPRICP, how will EF know to join them on the ITEMNO property?

Comment: @bkosh2 it will create a new foreign key property, and make the referential constraint use it. you can change the referential constraint from the properties dialog, and then delete the extra foreign key property. Note that if you have a foreign key specified in the database before hand, it should (I think) have automatically generated associations to match the foreign keys. If you don't have referential integrity in your database already (this is a sort of weak relationship) it's possible it might not work to create an association. (For example you'll likely have problems with NODASHITEMNO).

Comment: @Sahuagin when I add associations, navigation properties, and constraints in my .edmx file, I get the error: **Running transformation: Properties referred by the Principal Role ICPRICP must be exactly identical to the key of the EntityType PPPLTDModel.ICPRICP referred to by the Principal Role in the relationship constraint for Relationship PPPLTDModel.ORDERFORMDUMPICPRICP. Make sure all the key properties are specified in the Principal Role.** Also, what should the multiplicity be when I'm making associations? Should it be 1..1, 1..0, or 1..*?

Comment: @bkhosh2 The association needs to be a foreign key relationship. it sounds like maybe the fields you're using are not set as primary keys. The multiplicity should match the database. If there's one record in each table that are associated, that's 1-1. If there's a group of records in one table for each one record in another, that's 1-*. etc. Wish I could help you in person or something, but it may not be something that can be solved by talking about it over text.

Comment: I see `where (allowinbc = 'Yes' or allowinab = 'Yes')` in the SQL but the LINQ version seems to use `&&` rather than `||`. That could easily make a big difference.

Comment: Seperation of layers anyone? Why are you moving this data logic out of the Data Layer? Leave it in the DB where it will be most efficient. Your options then become A) Create a procedure and call the procedure from your EF of choice B) Create a view and use Linq / EF to query the View.

Comment: Running as a EF / Linq query (or even against a view for that matter) will never match the performance of running as a stored procedure. Plus you gain atomicity and have a clean gauranteed isolation level for the transaction.

Comment: @HBomb Omg... I don't know why I haven't thought of that. Lol. I feel stupid. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: It happens LOL. I submitted an answer since I'm trying to build rep.

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Above 4.1? You want to use ExecuteStoreQuery instead of ExecuteFunction.

Comment: @HBomb I'm using EF 5.

Comment: You also want to give the parameters name within the first argument. So something like ....... return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<PRODUCT_PROCEDURE_Result>("PRODUCT_PROCEDURE @search", USERIDParameter);

Comment: Without that parameter name (@search) being called out after the name of the procedure, it was probably returning null because it was running the proc with null as the value of the (@search) parameter. Try copy pasting my code from the comment above this and let me know.

Comment: @HBomb When I try adding `SqlParameter userId = new SqlParameter("@USERID", USERID);` and `((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<PRODUCT_PROCEDURE_Result>("PRODUCT_PROCEDURE @USERID", USERIDParameter);` to my PRODUCT_PROCEDURE method, I get the error **No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter to a known managed provider native type**

Comment: Whoops, forgot something else. You need to change `var USERIDParameter = USERID != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("USERID", USERID) :
                new ObjectParameter("USERID", typeof(string));`

Comment: Instead change the type ObjectParameter to SqlParameter:             `var USERIDParameter = USERID != null ?
                new SqlParameter("USERID", USERID) :
                new SqlParameter("USERID", typeof(string));`

Comment: @HBomb even after I change it to that code, I get a NullReferenceException

Comment: Can you update the question with the updated code so I can see it all? thx

Comment: @HBomb I updated my question to show the two different methods ExecuteStoreQuery, and ExecuteFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the Sql in a stored Procedure, you could just use EF to call the procedure. Here's one way:

```
 var searchParameter = new SqlParameter("@search", mySearchValue);
    this.Database.SqlQuery<YourEntityTypeForReturnVal>("MyProcedureName, @search", searchParameter);
```

You can that create a parameterized stored procedure as a wrapper for your Sql:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedureName
    @search varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- Copy and paste your existing Sql Query here, minus the variable declaration

END
```

Sometimes the best (and hardest) thing we can do as developers is to take a step back and ask "*should* I be doing it this way" instead of asking "*how* do I do it this way."

Comment: I just realized that I can't use a view because I have to join tables using variables to get the info I need. You can't use variables in an SQL view. For example: `LEFT JOIN PPPLTD.dbo.WEBLOGINACCESS ON WEBLOGINACCESS.[USER] = 'brian'`. The databases I'm working with are just really complicated. They are all set up like that to run propriety, custom software. Looks like my only choices are using raw SQL, or getting that long LINQ query to work... I really appreciate your help. It definitely makes more sense to use a view rather than joining a whole bunch of tables in LINQ!

Comment: You can just use a parameterized stored procedure and pass your variables as parameters. If you need help setting up a parameterized proc, I can amend the answer.

Comment: yeah, that would be great if you could show me how to set that up.

Comment: The whole reason I'm trying to use LINQ is so I can use the `.Contains()` method on the results to get more efficient search results. If the parameterized stored procedure will prevent me from using that, then I don't want you to go through the extra effort of changing your answer.

Comment: Gotcha... that can be done in a proc with the Like statement and % wildcard operator. I'll post it up in a bit when I get back to my other computer (2 or 3 hours). Its pretty quick

Comment: I'm already using `LIKE '%search%'` in my SQL. If there is some way I could get all the results without the LIKE % while passing a username parameter to it, that would be great. That way, I can still use the `Contains()` method in LINQ. For example, creating a parameterized stored procedure for the username variable and then calling that in EF and using a `where Contains` clause in LINQ.

Comment: Updated... does this now make sense? You pass the value of search as a parameter to the Stored Proc. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I am trying to execute my stored procedure through EF and use a LINQ where clause to filter the results, however, the execution of the stored procedure from EF is giving me a NullReferenceException. I've updated my questions to show my new code.

Comment: I found out that when I have `var products = db2.PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(username).ToList()` alone, it returns results, but as soon as I try to add a `where` clause on it, it returns null.

Comment: Oh, its the deferred execution of EF. Try `var products = db2.PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(username).ToList().Where
                        (item => item.basedescription.Contains(searchword) 
                         || item.info.Contains(searchword)
                         || item.itemno.Contains(searchword)
                         || item.itemno.Contains(searchword.Replace("-", ""))
                         || item.upc.Contains(searchword));`

Comment: Funny, I just wrote a response to another SO question that talks about that. I just added a tolist in between the procedure and the where extension method, which forces immediate execution. Alternatively, you can call `var products = db2.PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(username).ToList();` and then `var filteredProducts = products.Where (item => item.basedescription.Contains(searchword) || item.info.Contains(searchword) || item.itemno.Contains(searchword) || item.itemno.Contains(searchword.Replace("-", "")) || item.upc.Contains(searchword));`

Comment: Even after I do that, it still return null.

Comment: When I take out all the `||` conditions after the first condition (`var products = db2.PRODUCT_PROCEDURE(username).ToList().Where(item => item.basedescription.Contains(searchword));`), it works. For some reason, I can only filter by one condition at a time.

Comment: That's bizarre... I'd eliminate each part of the or clause until you find the one giving you problems. You should be able to chain them like you have just fine. Id also check the datatype of every variable in your PRODUCT_PROCEDURE‌​_Result type and make sure they're all strings (if they appear in this where clause.

Comment: For some reason, the **info** property is the one giving me problems...

Comment: What type is the info property on the PRODUCT_PROCEDURE_Result object?

Comment: info is a string, in the database, it is type varchar(max)

Comment: Lol I just realized that there are some null values in my database for info. You've helped me so much! I really appreciate it! If it weren't for your stored procedure comment, I wouldn't have solved this issue.

Comment: No worries mate... that would have been a *nightmare* to put as directly linq to entities ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm arriving after the battle, but could this be a job for [QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb)? You can paste your SQL into a query template as is, but it stays in your application (easier source-control, versioning, maintenance). And the generated classes make it directly usable from your application code.

Comment: This looks pretty cool! I'll try this out when I get a chance. Thank you.